# Simple way to implement a GUI for input math formula?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, math, user-interface

How can I implement a guided user interface for input math formulas and expresions? There is any GUI that I can embed in my page. An analogy is a date picker for entering the date.

Comment: Take a look at how they do it over at [math.stackexchange.com](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/community/mathjax-in-use/mathjax-in-use-websites/). No GUI, but the markdown is about as simple as it can get for complex formulas.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to create quizes for students  in which they dont have to enter the answer using latex or plain text

Comment: Aside from the question of complexity (do you just want exponents and variables, or everything up to advanced calculus expressions?), this is an off-topic question for StackOverflow because you're asking us to recommend a tool from some other site. I'm afraid you'll have to do your own research, or ask on a different forum like Reddit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/), made with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. You can add it to your page and then type math formulas as easily as writing.

Comment: Nice, but strange tool.  If you have written `a+b`, your are unable to convert it easily to `\sqrt{a+b}`.